# Android : How to fix hindi text cut in android 4.1.1 version?

Tags: java, android, textview

I am developing an application ,where Hindi font is used. Which display Hindi text in detail. so, I set Hindi typeface in application.In my app Hindi text display perfectly but on right end side,Hindi text display cut.

TextView  configs I am using:

```
     <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Small Text"
               android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
```

how can i show complete words with Hindi fonts?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your XML containing this view.

Comment: Have you tried running this in some device instead of emulator? If yes, was it giving the same outcome?

Comment: this issue only shown in 4.1.1 device.all other devices display Hindi Text  perfect.

Comment: Cut as in? Do they shift to next line or do they get out of view?

Comment: half word doesn't shift next Line,it cut at end of line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is bug in Android 4.1.1 see this link https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34432